# .htaccess Mod Rewrite Issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have following rewrite rule in htaccess and its not working for first part for EventList.php. Will appreciate some help to figure out whats wrong. I am adding this in a wordpress website htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule    ^Local-Event/([0-9]*)$    /Eventbrite.php?page=$1   [QSA]  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: What url are you going to and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @starkeen I have a custom .php page called Eventbrite.php . When a url called Local-Event/1 is hit I want to redirect to Eventbrite.php?page=1.